# Numerical verification of the estimate:

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, asymptotics

How to verify numerically with considerable accuracy in Mathematica the following :

> $$\int_2^x\dfrac{1}{z\Gamma(\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)])}dz\sim\ln(\ln(x))$$

?

I need more suitable and better code for it as you can see integrand oscillates wildly.

Any help is appreciated

I removed my code as I know it isn't going to help after x =10.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I used normal NIntegrate and calculated some values but I need bigger values say 10^3 or 10^4 with accuracy.

Comment: Could you put the Mathematica code you are using?

Comment: Submitted the code; anything to comment?

Comment: The definition of `myInt` makes no sense: what would it mean to call `myInt[3]` for instance? Did you mean something like `myInt[zMax_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[myF[z], {z, 2, zMax}]`?

Comment: Looks like 4 options:  (1)  Can't do it because it oscillates too much, (2)  Someone  here can help you adjust the integration method if that's possible, (3)  You can review "Advanced Integration methods" under NIntegrate help and try to adjust the integration method yourself.  There is a special section on oscillation integrands.  I tried a few without success.  Can also search "integrating highly oscillating integrands" here that may be of help, (4)  Somehow transform the integrand to a workable form.

Comment: Removing the code makes this into something less than a complete question. Which might get it closed.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I know that sir but the code is completely useless as it's showing very eccentric values after some threshold

Comment: Is there a good reason to believe this integral is not O(log(n)) ?